# react native http request JSON Parse error

Tags: json, react-native, utf-8, httprequest

1. the error occurs sometimes but not all the time. (I keep pressing *reload* until it resume normal)
2. the error occurs on android emulator but never on iphone.

> JSON Parse error: Expected '}' tryCallOne
>       C:\Users\xxx\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:37:14 
>       C:\Users\xxx\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:123:25
>   _callTimer
>       C:\Users\xxx\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:152:14
>   _callImmediatesPass
>       C:\Users\xxx\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:200:17
>   callImmediates
>       C:\Users\xxx\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:473:30
>   __callImmediates
>       C:\Users\xxx\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:337:6
>   
>       C:\Users\xxx\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:135:6
>   __guard
>       C:\Users\xxx\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:314:10
>   flushedQueue
>       C:\Users\xxx\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:134:17

it's just a very typical http request

```
  fetchArticle(id) {
    fetch("http://domain/api/articles/"+id)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          console.log(result);
          image_path = result.image_path;
          data = result.data;
          images = [];
          data.slides.forEach(function (el, index) {
           var image = image_path + "/" + el;
           //console.log(image);
           images.push({url:image});
          });
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            data: data,
            image_path: image_path,
            images: images,
          });
          //console.log(this.state.data);
          //console.log(this.state.images);
        },
        (error) => {
          console.error(error);
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
          });
        }
      )
  }
```

I have totally no idea what's wrong with it. please help. thank you!

updated:

API response data

> {"id":1,"title":"\u9999\u6e2f\u53cd\u4fee\u4f8b\u98a8\u6ce2\u6301\u7e8c\uff0c\u4e0d\u5c11\u6e2f\u5546\u7a4d\u6975\u90e8\u7f72\u64f4\u5f35\u6d77\u5916\u696d\u52d9\uff0c\u5206\u6563\u98a8\u96aa\u3002","heart":1,"address":"rewerfwr
>   fdsf sdfsdf
>   sdf","content":"
>
> 擬申請「第二家園」\r\n《蘋果》早前亦到吉隆坡訪問當地電商情況，近年中國科網龍頭大舉進軍當地市場，
>
> 如龍頭Shopee（創辦人為天津人李小冬）及Lazada（2016年被阿里巴巴收購）、淘寶亦十分流行，市場亦有Lelong.my等當地企業，競爭相當激烈。\r\n\r\n其中於巴生樓上店開設插花班、「Rose
>   Are
>   Red」聯合創辦人楊舒文表示，由於舖租僅1,000元令吉（約1,879港元），惟距離市區較遠，要靠網上吸引客人；她指對比不少當地盛行的電商，「客人見到產品的同時，</p>
>
> 亦會見到其他同款產品，好容易淨比較價錢而冇考慮質素」。而掌舖可直接將商品上載到網上製成獨立網頁，所以深受不懂網頁製作的店主歡迎。\r\n</p>
>
> \r\n吳家嘉提到，大馬「第二家園」計劃近日成為香港熱門話題，他指如當地業務成熟，亦會考慮申請。</p></p>\n","fee":"\u7531\u500b\u5225\u9598\u53e3\u5c01\u9589"}

i have tried another non-chinese request with the same api call (different id) and it has no any json parse error on android emulator. Therefore I suspect it's related to UTF8 or charset problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the response isn't sending any object to be parsed.
Checking the res.status before doing res.json() would be helpfull to prevent that error.
I don't know if it is your own API, but if you are expecting an object only when the request succeeded, try setting the response status in the back-end (let's say, 201), and check in the front-end if the res.status is 201 before doing res.json().

Of course, if you are also expecting an object when the request failed in some specific cases, do the same for the errors and set a response status to be checked in front-end before doing the res.json()

Once it is done, you can console.log the res.status when the above conditions are not fulfilled, and maybe share the result so we can help you investigate what happened ?

Comment: thank you. yes the api is my own api and it has set to be 200 response and i have also added application/json;charset=UTF-8 in header. after some tempts, now i suspect it's related to utf-8 problem. please check out my update. thanks again.

Comment: i have also added JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE for the api response in backend.

Comment: Hi ! 
So i checked your json, and i saw this post : http://qnimate.com/json-parse-throws-unexpected-token-error-for-valid-json/ , 
it seems like json file cannot contain \n nor \r nor \t nor \f
I was able to parse the json you provided with the solution proposed in the link , tested inside an IOS app (i currently cannot test in android), but i think you might need to do this in your back-end before sending it in the response. I will try it tonight in an android application as well, keep us updated !